# Store hash with array as value in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I want to store hash with array as value

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :sub_order, Hash
end

class OrderController
   def create
     Order.create(order_params)
   end

   def order_params
     params.require(:order).permit(sub_order: {first_sub_order: []})
   end
end
```

The problem with this is the value given for `suborder[:first_sub_order]` not storing in a given order. How to make sure we store in the given order.

Comment: What Postgres version are you using?

Comment: postgres version is 10.5

Comment: Do you have an example of the object you're trying to store?

Comment: example is {"first_sub_order"=>["one","two","three"]}

Comment: What do you mean by "not storing in a given order"?

Comment: The parameter i am passing is {"first_sub_order"=>["one","two","three"]}. But it is getting stored in random order. example is {"first_sub_order"=>["two","one","three"]}

Comment: How're you storing this attribute (column) in the database? Do you have the migration file?